# How to extend user control using control template?

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and I want to understand how to extend an UserControlBase class adding some control in other user control child.
In detail I have this sample UserControlBase with two buttons defined in control template:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControlBase"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Decorator" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Button x:Name="Button1" Click="Button1Click">Button1</Button>
                <ContentPresenter />
                <Button x:Name="Button3" Click="Button3Click">Button3</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Now I would like extend UserControlBase adding Button 2 in UserControlChild:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControlChild"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Decorator}">
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Click="Button2_Click">Button2</Button>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

This code doesn't work because "Decorator" could not be resolved. I don't Know how to link from UserControlBase. I Know that if I put control template in App.xaml this works but my purpose is to extend the UserControlBase.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property in your base class that would get the template for you, like so :

```
public ControlTemplate Decorator
{
    get { return FindResource("Decorator") as ControlTemplate; }
}
```

Then, your child class should be of type UserControlBase instead of UserControl and you bind your template to it. So your child class would look like this :

```
<UserControlBase x:Class="Test.UserControlChild"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Test"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Name=UserControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ContentControl Template="{Binding Decorator, ElementName=UserControl}">
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Click="Button2_Click">Button2</Button>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControlBase>
```

Another solution for this is to put your ControlTemplate in a ResourceDictionary instead of inside the UserControlBase resources and load this dictionary inside your UserControlChild control. Then you would be able to use it from the child control.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try first method and I receive error 'Test.UserControlBase' cannot be the root of XAML file because it was defined using XAML. I read that it is not possibile to inherits XAML.

Comment: Since your UserControlBase does not have xaml but a control template, you can make it a CustomControl instead of a UserControl. You will have to declare your template in a resource dictionary (like the second method).

Comment: I'll try to use ResourceDictionary as you said for the second method. Thanks.